# Caliburn micro ViewModel is not picking up a message from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Following my learning of MVVM using Caliburn.micro framework... I'm trying to communicate two viewModels sending data through the EventAggregator like this (code with "no sense", just for test):

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace TOP
{
[Export(typeof(MainWindowViewModel))]
public class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
{
    readonly IWindowManager windowManager;
    private readonly IEventAggregator events;
    private bool _Logged;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainWindowViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager, IEventAggregator events)
    {
        DisplayName = "TOP";
        this.events = events;
        events.Subscribe(this);
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
        windowManager.ShowDialog(new LoginViewModel(events));

    }

    public bool Logged
    {
        get { return _Logged; }
        set
        {
            _Logged = value;
            if(_Logged== true) 
                InitiateApp();
        }
    }

    public void Handle(LoginEvent message)
    {
        Logged = message.Logged;
    }

    private void InitiateApp() {
        ActivateItem(new TwoWindowViewModel());
        }
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.cs

```
namespace TOP{ 

 [Export(typeof(IScreen))]
    public class LoginViewModel : Screen
    {
        private readonly IEventAggregator _events;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public LoginViewModel(IEventAggregator events)
        {

           DisplayName = "Login";
           _events = events;
           Login();
        }


       public void Login()
       {
           _events.Publish(new LoginEvent(true));
       }
    }
}
```

LoginEvent.cs

```
    namespace TOP
    {
        public class LoginEvent
        {
           public LoginEvent(bool logged) 
           {
               Logged = logged;
           }

         public bool Logged { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Why the *Handle* method of *MainWindowViewModel* is not picking up the published message from *LoginViewModel*?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MainWindowViewModel` needs to implement `IHandle<LoginEvent>`. You already defined the method with the correct signature, so you only are missing the part where you actually tell the compiler that you implement the interface:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
    : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<LoginEvent>
```

More info can be found in [the documentation](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator).